# Pass the choices from selectInput on server side inside group_by function in Shiny app

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, group-by, selectinput

I would like to pass the user selection to a `group_by` function in Shiny apps!
The following code does not work, since the `input$bearkdown` is considered as a character!

How I could fix that?

```
dat = structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001), month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Quarter = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), project = c("DKF", 
    "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", 
    "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", "DKF", 
    "DKF"), value = c(135.172264747094, 128.304968251943, 124.552331218312, 
    72.9910740042406, 78.3565950925784, 93.7813954394283, 65.906459417623, 
    67.4455518391957, 100.287050913478, 96.6700531783534, 106.789122585464, 
    91.1228414774245, 88.8192557763821, 100.949844928465, 92.3481876481075, 
    82.5695257044659, 78.2314855696782, 58.656187528325, 59.863983014387, 
    91.5297764110538)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")




library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = 'breakdown',
                      label = 'Breakdown',
                      choices = c("Yearly"="year","Quarterly"="Quarter","Monthly"="month"),selected="Monthly")
        ),

        mainPanel(
           DT::dataTableOutput("datTB")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$datTB <- DT::renderDataTable({
      
      df <- dat%>%
        group_by(input$breakdown)%>%
        mutate(LongTermWI = mean(value,na.rm = T))
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `dplyr::across` and a second option would be to use the `.data` pronoun from the `rlang` package:

Using `across`:

```
group_by(across(input$breakdown)))
```

Using `.data`:

```
group_by(.data[[input$breakdown]])
```

Example code using `across`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = 'breakdown',
                  label = 'Breakdown',
                  choices = c("Yearly"="year","Quarterly"="Quarter","Monthly"="month"),selected="Monthly")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("datTB")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$datTB <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    df <- dat%>%
      group_by(across(input$breakdown)) %>%
      mutate(LongTermWI = mean(value,na.rm = T))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3069
```

[image]

Comment: Given the use of `group_by` and `mean`, I think OP may want `summarise` rather than `mutate`...

Comment: @Limey Yeah. Probably you are right. But as I don't know what the OP had in mind I'm always a bit reluctant in changing more than demanded.

Comment: Fair point.  And as you got the vote, you seem to be correct! :=)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your `renderDataTable` in addition to the one you identify.

First, your version asigns the mutated table to an object but doesn't return it.  Next, you use `mutate` rather than `summairise`.

I think this gets you close to what you want:

```
  output$datTB <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dat%>%
      group_by(!! as.symbol(input$breakdown))%>%
      summarise(LongTermWI = mean(value,na.rm = T))
  })
```

If you want to group by month or quarter within year, then you have a bit more work to do.